# Python ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (124,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (124,13)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I would like to normalize a training and test data set using `MinMaxScaler` in `sklearn.preprocessing`. However, the package does not appear to be accepting my test data set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read in data.
df_wine = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data', 
                      header=None)
df_wine.columns = ['Class label', 'Alcohol', 'Malic acid', 'Ash',
                   'Alcalinity of ash', 'Magnesium', 'Total phenols',
                   'Flavanoids', 'Nonflavanoid phenols', 'Proanthocyanins',
                   'Color intensity', 'Hue', 'OD280/OD315 of diluted wines',
                   'Proline']

# Split into train/test data.
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df_wine.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = df_wine.iloc[:, 0].values
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
                                                    random_state = 0)

# Normalize features using min-max scaling.
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
mms = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_norm = mms.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_norm = mms.transform(X_test)
```

When executing this, I get a `DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.` along with a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (124,) (13,) (124,)`.

Reshaping the data still yields an error.

```
X_test_norm = mms.transform(X_test.reshape(-1, 1))
```

This reshaping yields an error `ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (124,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (124,13)`.

Any input on how to get fix this error would be helpful.

Comment: When you have shape errors, the first thing you need to do is display the shape of all arrays that go into your problem  In this case `X_train` and `X_test`, may be more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partitioning of train/test data must be specified in the same order as the input array to the [`train_test_split()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function for it to unpack them corresponding to that order.

Clearly, when the order was specified as `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test`, the resulting shapes of `y_train` (`len(y_train)=54`) and `X_test` (`len(X_test)=124`) got swapped resulting in the `ValueError`.

Instead, you must:

```
# Split into train/test data.
#                   _________________________________
#                   |       |                        \
#                   |       |                         \
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)                                        
# |          |                                      /
# |__________|_____________________________________/
# (or)
# y_train, y_test, X_train, X_test = train_test_split(y, X, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Normalize features using min-max scaling.
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
mms = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_norm = mms.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_norm = mms.transform(X_test)
```

produces:

```
X_train_norm[0]
array([ 0.72043011,  0.20378151,  0.53763441,  0.30927835,  0.33695652,
        0.54316547,  0.73700306,  0.25      ,  0.40189873,  0.24068768,
        0.48717949,  1.        ,  0.5854251 ])

X_test_norm[0]
array([ 0.72849462,  0.16386555,  0.47849462,  0.29896907,  0.52173913,
        0.53956835,  0.74311927,  0.13461538,  0.37974684,  0.4364852 ,
        0.32478632,  0.70695971,  0.60566802])
```

Comment: So he's training on the 13 feature set, and testing on a 1 feature set.  That accounts for the unusual error message.  Shape error in sklearn questions are common, but not ones involving `non-broadcastable`.

Comment: If his dense layer doesn't match the number of his features, then this will cause that non-broadcastable error as well.