# Split Xy matrix into X and y

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

If I have a matrix `Xy` that I want to split into a matrix `X` and an array `y`, I usually do this

```
X, y = Xy[:, :-1], Xy[:, -1]
```

Is there a better way to do this using `scikit-learn` or `numpy`? I feel like it's a very common operation.

Comment: That's common only within the `learn` framework.  There's nothing special about such a split in `numpy` terms.  Even `np.split` will use that kind of indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj If you're criticizing my use of the `numpy` tag, I included it because I figured there would be a numpy method that answered my question. Also, the matrix itself is a numpy matrix. Furthermore, this method could also be used outside of sklearn if you're doing something like `numpy.linalg.solve`

Comment: Should `y` be 1d?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes. Hence `[:, -1]` instead of `[:, :-1]`

Comment: Nothing wrong with the tag.  `sklearn` is built on `numpy`.  It's just that I've only seen this particular split in `sklearn` questions.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/ is a `sklearn` page where `X` is (samples, features) and `y` is (samples,).  But I think I've also seen learning examples where `y` is (samples,1), or even (samples, out_features).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NumPy built-in [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) -

```
X, y = np.split(Xy,[-1],axis=1) # Or simply : np.split(Xy,[-1],1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [93]: Xy
Out[93]: 
array([[6, 2, 0, 5, 2],
       [6, 3, 7, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 3, 1, 3],
       [1, 3, 7, 1, 7]])

In [94]: X, y = np.split(Xy,[-1],axis=1)

In [95]: X
Out[95]: 
array([[6, 2, 0, 5],
       [6, 3, 7, 0],
       [3, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 7, 1]])

In [96]: y
Out[96]: 
array([[2],
       [0],
       [3],
       [7]])
```

Note that `np.split` would produce `y` as `2D`. To have a `1D` slice, we need to use `np.squeeze(y)` there.

Also, these slices would be views into original array, so no additional memory required there -

```
In [104]: np.may_share_memory(Xy, X)
Out[104]: True

In [105]: np.may_share_memory(Xy, y)
Out[105]: True
```

Comment: I think split uses slice indexing like the OP's., `[:, :-1],[:,[-1]]`

Comment: This `y` is (4,1)` shaped.

Answer (score 1):

`np.split` uses `np.array_split`.  That in turn does:

```
sub_arys = []
sary = _nx.swapaxes(ary, axis, 0)
for i in range(Nsections):
    st = div_points[i]
    end = div_points[i + 1]
    sub_arys.append(_nx.swapaxes(sary[st:end], axis, 0))
```

`swapaxes` is needed with `axis=1`; or without the swapping:

```
 sub_arys = []
 for ...:
    sub_arys.append(ary[:, st:end])
 return sub_arys
```

i.e. the same as:

```
In [388]: ary=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [389]: [ary[:,0:3], ary[:,3:4]]
Out[389]: 
[array([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 8,  9, 10]]), 
 array([[ 3],
        [ 7],
        [11]])]
```

`split` like this keeps the original number of dimensions.

Wrapping your code in a function gives something that will be as fast, if not faster:

```
def xysplit(ary):
    return ary[:,:-1], ary[:,-1]

X, y = xysplit(ary)
```

produces:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 8,  9, 10]]), 
array([ 3,  7, 11])
```

When I commented that this seems to be more common in `sklearn` contexts I had in mind questions like

[Python ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (124,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (124,13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669995/python-valueerror-non-broadcastable-output-operand-with-shape-124-1-doesnt-m)

```
X = df_wine.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = df_wine.iloc[:, 0].values
....
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, ...
```

`X` and `y` are 2d and 1d arrays, pulled in this case from a columns of a pandas dataframe. `train_test_split` is used to split `X` and `y` into training and testing groups.  If there is a special `X,y` splitter, it would be in the `sklearn` package, not `numpy`.

[Python - NumPy array_split adds a dminesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841003/python-numpy-array-split-adds-a-dminesion)

```
 train_inputs = train[:,: -1]
 train_outputs = train[:, -1]
```